# Silex Pimple service implementation

Tags: silex, pimple

Inside my Silex app I need a function which basically does a file_get_contents() my idea was to use something like

```
$app['funky_service'] = function () {
$content = file_get_contents();
return $content;
}
```

this is working fine, but how can I pass parameters to this function? I can call it like this

```
$fs = $app['funky_service'];
```

but passing arguments to it is still puzzling my

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the services chapter in the silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/services.html#protected-closures), you need to protect your function if you want to store it as a parameter:

```
$app['function_parameter'] = $app->protect(function ($resource) {
    $content = file_get_contents($resource);
    return $content;
});

$example = $app['function_parameter']('http://example.com');
```

Comment: Ah... I wasn't sure if I was missing some call to Pimple. I should have tested my code in my answer first. This answer should be marked as excepted

Comment: What is the benefit of using $app->protect() instead of creating a static helper method and use it anywhere in the code?